# TFS EventHandler to disable save option

Tags: c#, plugins, tfs, event-handling, listener

**We need to cancel 'save' workitem if AreaPath has less than 3 levels**.
We already saw a workaround to use prohibited values AreaID (doesn't solve, we have so many areapaths to do this manually), already try to copy that value to a String, but it doesn't work.

Is there some kind of plugin, client or server side?

We have some server plugins with ISubscriber, but, they work Async, so, all notificationType is 'Notification' and we cannot catch DecisionPoint, when we get the request the workitem seems to be already saved.

1. Do you know how can we get DecionType and if this is sync mode?
2. Do you have some example how to implement and Event WorkItemPreSaveEventHandler?
3. Do you know how can we implement a listener for pre saved work item?
4. Do you have some sugestion to solve our problem?

Thank you all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already finish this job, and maybe could be interesting for someone, so, what we made to do this was really simple.

We have a customcontrol, so, we have a bind to do this validation. If Areapath has less than 3 levels, we instantiate a new error:

```
bind: function (workitem) {
    this._base(workitem);               
    this._control.bind("click", delegate(this, this._onClick));
    this._workItemChangeDelegate = function (sender, args) {
        if (this._workItem.getField("System.AreaPath") != null) {

            if (this._workItem.getField("System.AreaPath").getValue().split("\\").length < 4) {
                error = new Error("Please insert at least 4 levels");
                this._workItem.setError(error);
            }
        }
    }

    workitem.attachWorkItemChanged(VSS.Core.delegate(this, this._workItemChangeDelegate));
},

unbind: function (workItem) {
    this._base(workItem);

    if (workItem != null) {
        workItem.detachWorkItemChanged(this._workItemChangeDelegate);
        delete this._workItemChangeDelegate;
    }
},
```

For VS, implement IWorkItemControl, and add this one:

```
private void M_workItem_Saving(object sender, WorkItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        string areaPath = m_workItem.AreaPath.ToString();
        if ((int)areaPath.Split('\\').Length < 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Please insert at least 4 levels");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no decision point for work item changes. Changes are stored and then a notification is issued.So this will remove the options 1, 2 and 3.

As for option 4, you could create a custom work item control inheriting from the standard controls and implement your logic in there. You'll need to create a web and a windows variant, the latter for every Visual Studio version that's used on your TFS instance.

Your users will still be able to save new work items through Excel, MsProject and the API this way, as the UI validation rules are not executed in this context.

Basically, you should be keeping in mind that fields can be changed to values you want to block, and you'll need to have some compensating mechanism in place, be it reporting, generating email to warn the users, a dashboard widget which shows users in violation etc.

Comment: Hi jessehouwing, Thanks for your answer.
So, you are suggesting me to create a custom control to save the workitem, and in this button I can create all customization, right?

I read an article that previous versions of TFS, I'm working on TFS 2015 (2), there was a possibility to create a web site that has the hability to listen tfs port/ workitem actions. Is this possible on 2015? How?

About WorkItemPreSaveEventHandler, where usually this can be implemented?

Comment: No a custom area path control. But seriously, my real solution would be to educate the users and have a few work item queries to find offenders.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.
Last thing, do you where can I find documentation about TFS WebAccess extensions (VSS\Service, VSS\Utils\Core\VSS\Controls\Dialogs, TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls, ...) ?

Comment: There is pretty much no documentation available on these API's